# Can I convert an expression from a "linear style" to a "fractional style"?

Tags: output-formatting, algebraic-manipulation, rule

Is it possible to transform this expression

```
f = r + (s - r)/(1 + (a h)^n)^(1 - 1/n)
```

to a "fractional style" using rules?

```
rule = Power[Plus[1, Power[Times[a_, h_], n_]], 
       Plus[-1, Power[n_, -1]]] :> 
       Divide[1, Power[Plus[1, Power[Times[a, h], n]], Plus[1, -1/n]]]

f //. rule
```

Comment: What is the desired output in this case?

Comment: http://file.scirp.org/Html/1-1660130/6b3a9d92-11f2-4e57-96b8-3ef142c272e1.jpg

Comment: I am uncertain of your goals but is this of any use to you? `f /. c_*a_^b_ :> (Defer[#/#2] &[c, a^-b])`

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments above it seems my lucky guess is what you wanted:

```
f /. c_*a_^b_ :> (Defer[#/#2] &[c, a^-b])
```

[image]

If you find cases where this does not do what you want please give clear examples of input and desired output and I shall try to extend it to cover those as well.